# Differences between OpenTaps vs OpenERP

Tags: odoo, opentaps

Can someone let me know the difference between OpenTaps vs OpenERP

Size of OpenTaps - 276 MB - 2GB RAM - Java

Size of OpenERP  - 169 MB - 1GB RAM - Python Language - Java Connector - Last Update Nov 2013

I don't find clear differences between the two and confused which one is the best for inventory management.

Comment: Tool recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow (you're asking which is best for inventory management).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try them both.  They both good products and for me it ends up with your programming skills.  If you are a java guy i will suggest Opentaps or Ofbiz.